# VueJS Datepicker date and month exchange places

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I using this datepicker - [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker). When I submit the form which I am using the date and month places change. For example: 10/08/2018 (dd/MM/yyyy), after that vizualize as 08/10/2018, which ofcourse causes a lot of problems now. I read that the datepicker is using internally Date.parse for parsing the dates and from there comes the problem. However, how can I fix this?

```
<datepicker
  v-model="eoriModel.c1_date"
  placeholder="Choose a date"
  :format="DatePickerFormat"
  :clearButton="true"></datepicker>

DatePickerFormat: dd/MM/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datepicker provide [function-formatter](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#function-formatter), so you can use custom formatter:

```
<script>
  methods: {
    customFormatter(date) {
      var formattedDate;
      //  Parse date and format it according to your needs.
      return formattedDate;
    }
  }
</script>
<datepicker :format="customFormatter"></datepicker>
```

Comment: Had the same problem and tried to implement the same solution. It didn't work out for me. :(